# Creating Open Type font from True Type fonts?

Tags: fonts, opentype, ttf

I have a set of True Type font files which are different style of a given font. Say

```
 myfnt__.ttf  -> regular
 myfntB_.ttf  -> bold
 myfntI_.ttf  -> italic
 myfntBI.ttf  -> bold italic
```

I believe there's a way to wrap them all into a single otf file (say `myfnt.otf`) and having the corrent glyphs selected depending on the style (magic of OpenType).

Does anybody know if this is possible and how to do it? Or could provide any direction on where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would be possible to have several styles inside one OpenType font as Stylistic Sets, it is absolutely unrecommended and you would need to do this manually with professional font design software like FontLab, Glyphs or Robofont.

What you probably mean is combining special font files like small caps, tabular numerals, alternates or extended diacritics from Ye Olden Days to one OTF. That is perfectly acceptable, but there is still no automatic way to do that.